# Как сделать так чтобы при выборе tabItem цвет его заголовка менялся

Tags: c#, xaml

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе `TabItem` цвет его заголовка менялся?

```xml
<Window x:Class="SoftPizzaHut.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoftPizzaHut"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Управление закупками PizzaHut" MinHeight="700" MinWidth="1200"  FontSize="23.9"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
    TextElement.FontSize="13"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" 
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"        
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">

<Window.Resources>
    
        <!--Control colors.-->
        <Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
        <Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FFEE3A43</Color>
        <Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFEE3A43</Color>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
      Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
      Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            
                                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"    
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                (SolidColorBrush.Color)" >
                                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="#70EFEFEF" />
                                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        
                                    </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Panel.ZIndex="1"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                IsItemsHost="True"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                Background="Transparent" />
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
              Grid.Row="1"
              BorderThickness="1"
              CornerRadius="2"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
              KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                          Margin="4"
                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                     Value="#66FF000D" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
              BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"     
                            CornerRadius="0,0,0,0">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#0001FB11" />
                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                               EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#1C211AA9"
                              Offset="0.907" />
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFEE3A43" Offset="1"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFEE3A43" Offset="0.907"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#26FF0000" Offset="0.903"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#00F7418C" Offset="0.667"/>
                                            </GradientStopCollection>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                                </Border.Background>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          Margin="12,2,12,2"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="pizzastyle1" Color="#FFA71732"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="pizzastyle2" Color="#FFE20029"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFABAdB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Focus.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <Style x:Key="search" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource TextBox.Focus.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OpacityGrey" Color="#FFBDBDBD"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-34">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="833*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="367*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Margin="0,24,27,0" Source="/PizzaHut.svg.png" MinWidth="15" MaxWidth="150" MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="300" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="157" Height="141" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TabControl Margin="0,75,10,10" FontSize="20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <TabItem Header="Закупки" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
            <Grid/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Поставщики" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Grid/>
            </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Товары" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Grid/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <Expander Height="29" Header="Расширенный поиск" Margin="0,31,42,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#00000000" FontSize="20" Panel.ZIndex="1111" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="244" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontWeight="Normal">
            <Expander.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFEE3A43"/>
            </Expander.Foreground>
            <Grid Background="#8CE4E4E4" Margin="0,10,-540,-230" Width="783" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,51,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Поставщик" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="407"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Название товара" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="407" Height="36"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,124,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Категория" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="407"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="161,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,174,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label Content="Цена    От:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="281,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="136" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Style="{DynamicResource search}" Margin="16,24,32,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="485" Foreground="{DynamicResource OpacityGrey}" Padding="15,4,245,4" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderBrush="#A8ABADB3" Text="Поиск" LostKeyboardFocus="TextBox1_LostKeyboardFocus" GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox1_GotKeyboardFocus" Height="42"/>
        <Button Content="Найти" Margin="67,27,216,659" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вы работаете с WPF. Там при нажатии на элемент правой кнопкой мыши , появляется окно в котором можно править копию шаблона , а потом в нужный элемент подставить этот шаблон , ниже я привел пример кода в котором поменял цвет при наведении

```
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
       <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="red"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3EA0FE"/>
</Trigger>
```

А Так же там есть код при нажатии на вкладку

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3E68FE"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="ForestGreen"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/> 
                    </Trigger>
```

Вот так я подставил свой шаблон

```
 <TabItem  Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}" Margin="49,-2,-60,-1">
</TabItem>
```

Как создать копию шаблона!

[image: Правка копии]

Полностью весь шаблон

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"  Value="#797B8E"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                    <Border x:Name="Bd"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" >
                                        <ContentPresenter   x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="red"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3EA0FE"/>
                                       
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger>
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Bd" Value="0.6"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                       
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#3E68FE"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="ForestGreen"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                           
                        </Trigger>
    
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```